# Only root can mount /dev/sdb1 on /media/sdb1 - contribute to external usb drive

Tags: usb, fstab, automount, gvfs

I can't understand why, when I tried plug-in external USB driver in Ubuntu 12.04, I see next message:

```
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
mount: only root can mount /dev/sdb1 on /media/sdb1
```

Here is content of `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc                                       /proc           proc  nodev,noexec,nosuid       0  0  
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=5f5d330f-d5f2-4157-9496-94f1dce2f181  /               ext4  errors=remount-ro         0  1  
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=84747ef4-6f50-49bc-9df1-fcba364ba299  none            swap  sw                        0  0  

/dev/fd0                                   /media/floppy0  auto  rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8  0  0  
/dev/sdc1                                  /media/sdc1     vfat  uid=1000,noauto           0  0  
/dev/sdd1                                  /media/sdd1     vfat  uid=1000,noauto           0  0  
/dev/sdb1                                  /media/sdb1     vfat  uid=1000,noauto           0  0
```

And this is my current `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000e28b8

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   310484991   155241472   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       310487038   312580095     1046529    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       310487040   312580095     1046528   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 993 MB, 993001472 bytes
2 heads, 1 sectors/track, 969728 cylinders, total 1939456 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1             133     1939455      969661+   6  FAT16

Disk /dev/sdc: 4009 MB, 4009754624 bytes
16 heads, 32 sectors/track, 15296 cylinders, total 7831552 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xd8e1f237

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *          32     7831551     3915760    b  W95 FAT32
```

`sdc` and `sdb` - there are external usb drivers.

***Can I solve this trouble and mount all external usb drives automatically?***

Comment: Check your permissions. Post results of: `ls -l / | grep media` and `ls -l /media | grep sd`

Comment: @dan08 It all as `drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jun 14 11:04 bin;
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Aug 21 18:47 boot;
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jun  9 14:17 cdrom;` I don't know how to divide this line to parts

Comment: @dan08 of course they all exist, as `drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 20 22:00 sdc1/`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to add the `user` option to your `fstab`

```
/dev/sdc1    /media/sdc1     vfat  uid=1000,noauto,user           0  0  
/dev/sdd1    /media/sdd1     vfat  uid=1000,noauto,user           0  0  
/dev/sdb1    /media/sdb1     vfat  uid=1000,noauto,user           0  0
```

The `user` option allows any user to mount a device, as said in the man:

> Normally,  only  the  superuser can mount filesystems. However, when fstab contains the `user` option on a line, anybody can mount the corresponding system.

Or if you want any user to mount/unmount the drives use `users` instead:

```
/dev/sdc1    /media/sdc1     vfat  uid=1000,noauto,users           0  0  
/dev/sdd1    /media/sdd1     vfat  uid=1000,noauto,users           0  0  
/dev/sdb1    /media/sdb1     vfat  uid=1000,noauto,users           0  0
```

Man page:

> Only the user  that  mounted  a filesystem  can unmount it again.  If any user should be able to unmount, then use users instead of user in the fstab line.

**Note:** the `user` option also implies `noexec`, `nosuid`, and `nodev`, so if you need those options, you'll need to add their counterparts. For example, if you're going to need to execute binary files from the drive, you should add the option `exec`, so your options would be `uid=1000,noauto,user,exec`, and the same goes for the other two.

**Further reading: [Fstab - Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab#Options)**

Comment: As per your response, is the difference between the "user" and "users" that with "users" the user can umount as well, but not with "user"?

Comment: No, users allow any user to unmount the drive

Answer (score 2):

If you have an entry for a device in /etc/fstab, it will prevent the Ubuntu automatic mounter from mounting that device when plugged in.

I just tested this on my system which was automatically mounting my thumb-drive upon insertion:

```
// insert thumb-drive
$ grep gvfsd /proc/mount
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/msw/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=msw)
```

When I added the line

```
/dev/sdb1   /mnt    vfat    noexec 0 0
```

to /etc/fstab and inserted the thumb-drive, there was a flurry of activity by the process `gvfsd-udisks2-volume-monitor` which included opening and reading /etc/fstab (as shown by `strace`). The thumb-drive did not mount.

When I changed /etc/fstab by adding one character to comment out the entry:

```
#/dev/sdb1   /mnt    vfat    noexec 0 0
```

gvfsd-udisks2-volume-monitor became busy again and mounted the thumb drive. I didn't have to take out the thumb-drive and reinsert it, I didn't have to send a signal to gvfsd, so the automatic mounting daemon seems to be watching /etc/fstab for changes.

I don't know why it behaves this way, but the test was simple and repeatable.