# How to auto mount with full permissions using gnome-disk-utility?

Tags: permissions, mount, automount, gnome-disk-utility

I have `gnome-disk-utility` installed.  It mounts a secondary hard drive I have, but it does not do it with write or execute permissions.

How do I setup `gnome-disk-utility` to mount a hard drive with read, write, and execute permissions?

[image]

Per this other Ask Ubuntu question (https://askubuntu.com/a/769465/461996) it seems I should add `uid=1000,noauto,users` to the argument list.  I tried this, but still I do not have write or execute permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright.  This isn't a complete answer, but it works.

Based off another answer, I tried adding `users` assuming all users are in that category.  I guess this is only the case for users that have no other group (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/326782/132794)

I do not know how to add a permission that makes it so any user can have read/write permissions on this mount.  So that's why this is not yet a complete answer.

Anyways, the trick was `uid=1000`.  You can get your user id with `echo $UID` or just `id`.

---

Further, if you get your username with `whoami`, you can see what groups you are in with `groups [username]`.  Perhaps one of these groups is applicable to all users?  Perhaps not.

Answer (score 8):

The whole purpose of a GUI disk manager is to avoid this trouble.  This is why Linux is not used by my mother.

**Add the following to your mounting options.**

```
uid=1000,gid=1000
```

Here is the screenshot from the app.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my permission issue on a partition-mount by clicking that icon where you pick "Edit mount options" but I chose "Take Ownership" instead.

And I have these options: `nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,rw,exec`

Comment: Tks, that's exacly what I was looking for. 
This answer should be marked as the best as it does perfectly what was asked.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve full permissions, you need to add `rw,exec`. That will allow read/write and execution access.

Answer (score 0):

The man page for `gnome-disk-image-mounter` (which is what is being used by the Gnome Disk Utility to mount the images) says the following:

> By default the disk images are attached read-only, use the option --writable to change this.

So running `gnome-disk-image-mounter --writable` then selecting the image to mount mounts it writable. Adding the other command line options did not worked for me using version 3.36.3